# Prove that a bounded function's limit at infinity is zero when its derivative admits finitely many zeros

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be infinitely many times differentiable and $f$ is bounded.

1. Show that if $f^{(k)}$ has finitely many zeros then we have $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f^{(p)}(x)=0$ for all $p\in \{1, ..., k-1\}$.
2. Prove that, in this case, for $k\geq 2$, $f^{(k)}$ wanishes at, at least, $k-1$ points.

Thanks!

--

The thoughts I am having are:

If $f^{(k)}$ is unbounded, then $f^{(k-1)}$ is unbounded. But we have that $f$ is bounded. By contradiction, $f$ and all times of derivative of $f$ should be bounded.

Let $x_n$ be the last zero of $f^{(k)}$. Also let $|f^{(k-1)}|\leq L$. Because $\int_{x_n}^\infty\! f^{(k)} \, \mathrm{d}x=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f^{(k-1)}(x)-f^{(k-1)}(x_n)$, $|\int_{x_n}^\infty\! f^{(k)} \, \mathrm{d}x|\leq 2L$. So $\int_{x_n}^\infty\! f^{(k)} \, \mathrm{d}x$ is finite.

Because $f^{(k)}$ does not change sign on $(x_n,\infty)$, we have to have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f^{(k-1)}(x)=0$. Then by induction we can have $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f^{(p)}(x)=0$ for all $p\in \{1, ..., k-1\}$.

However, I know neither if it is correct nor how to write it down rigorously. Also have no idea about the second question.

Comment: What does it mean to say $f^{(k)}$ "admits finitely many zeros?"  Also, should $\lim_{x\to\pm}f^{(p)}(x)=0$ be $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f^{(p)}(x)=0$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. This is not a homework site and you need to show your work if you want people to help you in such questions.

Comment: @saulspatz "admits finitely many zeros" means "has finitely many zeros." And yes, it should be $x\to \pm\infty$. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: @Sam Tried to add some of my thoughts about these questions. Do they help a little?